# Surveying software with geocoding abilities

Tags: software-recommendations, geocoding, land-survey, tablet

My company is a market research firm looking for an integrated surveying software that has the potential to geocode on-the-fly via tablet device.

Requirements:
-Ability to collect rider questionnaire-type surveys on several bus routes
-Also a map feature that allows us to record several origin and destination points for each survey
-The map feature must be searchable (i.e. by intersections, addresses, or major place names)
-Ability to turn on/off layers in the map (bus routes for reference)
-Ability to work offline (optional, but preferred)

Comment: does the tablet have its own gps built in?

Comment: The tablets we'll be using will have GPS, we just need to collect points based off the rider's origin and destination (not our current location), hence why we need the search functionality